# ssis package importing data from email attachments to excel

Tags: ssis

I have got 100 plus email in a folder and all of them have got an attachment. I want to create a package which will copy the data from all email attachments in one excel sheet and also add a column which will have the received dates of those emails against the data.Can any one guide me how to do it with help of ssis package.

Comment: It would be easier to do this with powershell or vba. What is your mail server?

Comment: those mails are placed in folder not on mail server.

Comment: Just to clarify, a folder in your file system? What is the ext of the documents that contain an attachment?

Comment: .msg and those have .txt as attachment

Answer (score 0):

Not ssis but it should produce the desired result. Just change the path on the last line.

```
function Get-Attachment
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Path", Position=0, Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$Path,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="LiteralPath", Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$LiteralPath,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="FileInfo", Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$Item
    )

    Begin
    {
        remove-item $Path\attachments.xlsx
        $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
        $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $excel.visible = $true
        $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.add()
        $s1 = $workbook.Sheets.add()
        $s1.name = "Attachments"
        $cells= $s1.Cells
        $s1.range("A1:A1").font.bold = "true"
        $s1.range("A1:A1").cells="RecDate"
        $s1.range("B1:B1").cells="Data"
        $s1.range("B1:B1").font.bold = "true"   
    }
    Process
    {
        switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
        {
            "Path"        { $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path }
            "LiteralPath" { $files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $LiteralPath }
            "FileInfo"    { $files = $Item }
        }
        $row=2
        $col=2
        $files | % {
            $msgFn = $_.FullName
            if ($msgFn -notlike "*.msg") {
                return
            }
            $msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($msgFn)
            $rdate = $msg.ReceivedTime
            $msg.Attachments | % {
            $attFn = $msgFn -replace '\.msg$', " - Attachment - $($_.FileName)"
            if (Test-Path -literalPath $attFn) {
                    return
                }
                $_.SaveAsFile($attFn)
                Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $attFn
                $d = ( Get-Content -Path $attFn -Raw)
                $cells.item($row,$col)=$d.ToString()
                $cells.item($row,1) = $rdate
                $row++
            }
            $s1.range("A1:B1").EntireColumn.autofit() | out-Null
            $s1.range("A1:B1").EntireColumn.WrapText = $false | out-Null
        }
    }

    End
    {
        $workbook.SaveAs("$Path\attachments.xlsx")
    }
}

Get-Attachment -Path C:\Users\Administrator\pathtodir\
```

Comment: should use script task in order to execute the above

Comment: No, use Powershell.

Comment: If ssis is necessary, use an execute process task to start powershell then execute the script.

Comment: I have executed the script.
It has created a blank excel named attachments.xlsx and has got all the attachments from mail in the path mentioned.(created copy of attachments from mail naming 'Subjectline' - Attachment - 'Attachment name')

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand. It should do what you requested, is this not the case?

Comment: It is not copying all the data from the attachment eg: I have got 20000 plus lines of data in an attachment it has only copied 300 lines and moved to next email attachment,The data is not following end of line, it combines with 2nd, 3rd line and so on.Also the received mail dates are given in group rather than line wise.

Comment: to be precise it is copying only first 254 lines from each attachment

Comment: This may be an issue with excel, sorry, i have not had time to look into it.